# Hyperledger Caliper on Sample Repo

Tags: hyperledger, benchmarking, hyperledger-caliper

I'm setting up Hyperledger Caliper and using it to test the sample repo. While performing this:

```
npx caliper launch manager --caliper-workspace . --caliper-benchconfig benchmarks/scenario/simple/config.yaml --caliper-networkconfig networks/ethereum/1node-clique/networkconfig.json
```

I got these errors:

> `2022.05.30-13:14:17.377 error [caliper] [caliper-utils]   Unsuccessful command execution. Error code: 1. Terminating signal: null`

> `2022.05.30-13:14:17.377 error [caliper] [caliper-engine]  An error occurred while executing the start command: Error: Command failed: cd .; docker-compose -f ./networks/ethereum/1node-clique/docker-compose.yml up -d && sleep 60s`

> `2022.05.30-11:47:31.196 error [caliper] [cli-launch-manager] Benchmark failed with error code 3`

What's Benchmark failed with error code 3?

Comment: Looks like it failed to execute the command `cd .; docker-compose -f ./networks/ethereum/1node-clique/docker-compose.yml up -d && sleep 60s`

do you have `docker-compose` installed ?

Comment: @david_k yes. This is the version I'm using `docker-compose version 1.29.2, build 5becea4c`

Comment: You could try running that commanf yourself to see if it works (and remove it from the benchmark file). It's a convenience cmd to bring up a network before the benchmark runs

Comment: i tried running it but there were no errors. This is the log I got, `Creating network "1node-clique_default" with the default driver
Creating ethereum_clique ... done
usage: sleep seconds` @david_k

Comment: Looks like your environment doesn't like the `sleep` command as it is giving an error `usage: sleep seconds`. What platform are you running this on ?

Comment: i'm running this on ethereum. I did not edit the configuration files from the sample repo and this is the url:  "url": "ws://localhost:8546" @david_k

Comment: This seems to be an issue with Mac OS and it's sleep command being really old (compared to linux). You should be able to remove the `s` from the `60s` to fix it